# Can PM2 be used with compiled c programs

Tags: c, pm2

Is it possible to use pm2 with custom c programs?
If so, how is this accomplished?
Does it work well?
Is you are already using pm2 for node.js apps would it make sense to use it for a c program as well?

Answer (score 16):

In order to run an precompiled executable file or binary, you need to add `"exec_interpreter": "none"` and `"exec_mode"  : "fork_mode"` in your JSON file.

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"       : "binary",
    "script"     : "./binary",
    "exec_interpreter": "none",
    "exec_mode"  : "fork_mode"
  }]
}
```

Sources: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#start-any-process-type  and https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1776#issuecomment-157560622

Answer (score 6):

From testing it is as simple as specifying the executable file.  For example to run a c program compiled to a.out use `pm2 start a.out`.

Comment: How do you start it with flags though? Thanks

Comment: pm2 start app.js -- -a 23  # Pass arguments '-a 23' argument to app.js script